# String expression does not work with ng-bind directive whereas number expression does?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, expression, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

See below examples of AngularJS code:

**Ex. 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="" ng-init="quantity=1;cost=5">
            <p>Total in dollar: <span ng-bind="{{quantity * cost}}"></span></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output of above program is: **Total in dollar: 5**

**Ex. 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John';lastName='Doe'">
            <p>The full name is: <span ng-bind="{{firstName + ' ' + lastName}}"></span></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output of above program is: **The full name is:**

Why the full name is not appearing in output of second program?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `{{}}` interpolation again in `ng-bind` directive

```
ng-bind="(quantity * cost)"

ng-bind="firstName + ' ' + lastName"
```

The reason 1st got worked is the the evaluated output of `quantity * cost` which is `5` tries to evaluated with `scope` which is 5, but when we pass `firstName + ' ' + lastName`, it throws the error in console which is `$parser: Syntax` error.

The reason behind error is, 1st it tries to evaluate `{{}}` interpolated value which output would be `John Doe` & thereafter it evaluate result and try to search in the scope again, where it is trying to search `John Doe`(in correct variable name having space in it) in scope. Since it throws an error.

---

You can try one thing, change your `ng-bind` to have it without space like `ng-bind="{{firstName + lastName}}"`(just concatenation of two variables). You can see error will not happen in console. But still you will not see any output on screen as `JohnDoe` variable isn't available in scope. So just try to add some value for `JohnDoe` on `ng-init`(just for testing) like `ng-init="JohnDoe='Mytest'"`, it will display output.

> Preferred way to use `ng-bind` is without `{{}}`

Comment: Then how does it working in first example? It shouldn't have been working in first example as well.

Comment: I dont think the first one works either. Tried it out and both seems to be not working.here is a jsfiddle of it not working https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24828/ @PHPLover. Works if I make the changes suggest above. You might want to recheck your output again.

Comment: @Imprfectluck see here is the example 1st one worked but second one doesn't [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/a32clodMJcwFRNbzEjRZ?p=preview)

Comment: @Imprfectluck check console `window.angular.$$csp is not a function`

Comment: @PHPLover look at the updated in detail answer..that will answer your all question related curiosity. Thanks :)